# creating an object within a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, syntax

I am developing a web app. I have a disptacher servlet which successfully calls a JSP page, but this JSP has to read data from some other object... but it would find it...

this is the line which wont locate "BackendServer" class. It gives me a ClassNotFoundException error...

```
  <%=new BackendServer().run("getCar")%>
```

basically the above line of code is within the JSP... if  I remove it, the app runs well without the output of this line

I have imported BackendServer on top this way:

```
  <%@page import="com.servlet.java.*"%>
```

how can I make my JSP find my BackendServer?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: make sure your BackendServer class is really on your classpath! ClassNotFoundException - tells that it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a space like:

```
<%@ page import="com.servlet.java.*"%>
```

And make sure if the file comes from a jar, put the jar into the lib.

Comment: I only had to add a space between the @ char and the word 'page'

Thanks to Shreyos and everyone

Comment: you are welcome. And if you satisfied with the answer then you can accept after stackoverflow allows you to do that.

Comment: +1 since downvoter didn't consider the answer actaully helped TS

Answer (score 2):

Why do not you use Beans:

```
<jsp:useBean id="VarName" class="BackendServer"  scope = *page | request | session |application*/>
```

Answer (score 1):

write the fully qualified name. com.servlet.java.BackendServer is your class?

are you sure the jar of this class is in classpath of this web app?

where is the jar?

where is the app.

should be in common lib, global app container classpath or this web apps path

Comment: they are in the same app folder, all deployed. all available and compiled

Comment: which server are you using ? tomcat? jboss? exactly where have you deployed? are you sure there is no class init / static or other code in BackendServer that is throwing error so no class initialized. you have the source code?